# Springboot: BeanCreationException, Application run failed, but still running, How to kill the process?

Tags: java, spring-boot

When my Springboot application is trying to start:

I get a BeanCreationException (I know why the Bean can't be created, this is not the main issue)

I get the message: ***o.s.boot.SpringApplication: Application run failed***

When my application remains in this failing state, it starts to consume more resources, memory and CPU, I even hear the CPU fan working faster.

My questions are:

- Why if the application failed to start, does not stop/kill the
  process automatically?
- Is there a way to kill the process(stop the application) if the
  application failed to start? If a specific Bean can not be created
  how to stop the application?
- Why the application consumes more resources when is running in a
  failing state?

I read the Spring boot documentation trying to find details about this, but I didn't find answers.

Regards

Comment: Show some code, logging etc. there is too little information here. If at startup a bean fails to be created the application will automatically stop. So it appears as if this bean failure isn't part of the startup of the application but rather something else.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.